# Gremlin find all 'person' to 'person' connection

Tags: gremlin

Sample data: Tinker Modern

[image]

Query:

```
g.V()
.hasLabel("Person")
.bothE().bothV()
.hasLabel("Person")
.path()
.by(label())
```

Result:

```
['Person', 'knows', 'Person']
['Person', 'knows', 'Person']
['Person', 'created', 'Person']
['Person', 'knows', 'Person']
['Person', 'knows', 'Person']
['Person', 'knows', 'Person']
['Person', 'knows', 'Person']
['Person', 'created', 'Person']
['Person', 'created', 'Person']
['Person', 'knows', 'Person']
['Person', 'knows', 'Person']
['Person', 'created', 'Person']
```

**This result should not contain the 'created' edge since that is for person to software**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I re-wrote your traversal as:

```
g.V().
  hasLabel("person").
  bothE().bothV().
  hasLabel("person").
  path().
    by(label)
```

I think that you can expect to see "created" edges because you traverse `bothE()`, meaning that you start from a "person", and traverse both incoming and outgoing edges. Those edges might be "created" edges. Then, you do `bothV()` which means traverse from both the source and the target of those edges. Since some of those edges are "created" edges they will have a "person" on one side (the "person" vertex you started from) and a "software" on the other.

Perhaps it makes more sense if we look at one person:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').bothE('created').bothV().label()
==>person
==>software
```

Note that when we traverse on the "created" edge and do `bothV()` we get both a "person" (i.e. marko) and a "software". If we add a filter to get rid of "software":

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').bothE('created').bothV().hasLabel('person').values('name')
==>marko
```

we end up with "marko". The same thing is happening in your traversal. If you want to filter out "software" then you should get more specific with the edge label:

```
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   hasLabel("person").
......2>   bothE("knows").bothV().
......3>   hasLabel("person").
......4>   path().
......5>     by(label)
==>[person,knows,person]
==>[person,knows,person]
==>[person,knows,person]
==>[person,knows,person]
==>[person,knows,person]
==>[person,knows,person]
==>[person,knows,person]
==>[person,knows,person]
```

Or perhaps you don't need `bothV()`:

```
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   hasLabel("person").
......2>   bothE().otherV().
......3>   hasLabel("person").
......4>   path().
......5>     by(label)
==>[person,knows,person]
==>[person,knows,person]
==>[person,knows,person]
==>[person,knows,person]
```

or a little weird, but you could filter edges this way:

```
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   hasLabel("person").
......2>   bothE().filter(bothV().hasLabel('person').count().is(2)).bothV().
......3>   path().
......4>     by(label)
==>[person,knows,person]
==>[person,knows,person]
==>[person,knows,person]
==>[person,knows,person]
==>[person,knows,person]
==>[person,knows,person]
==>[person,knows,person]
==>[person,knows,person]
```

Anyway, that should be enough examples for you to consider - I'm sure there's other ways to make this work.

Comment: modified it as *g.V().hasLabel("X") .bothE().as("edge") .filter( bothV().hasLabel('X').and() .otherV().hasLabel('Y')) .bothV() .path() .select("edge") .by(label()) .dedup()* to suit my requirement and it gives me all the Edges as intended. thanks a lot.

Comment: I have a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510446/gremlin-get-edges-that-were-traversed) where I am trying to find out data similar to *Peter-(created)->lop<-(created)-josh-(created)->ripple*   if you could give me some guidance it will be great. thanks.